# Cleanup after fresh windows server 2003 installation

Tags: updates, windows-server-2003, windows-server

After installing Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2 and then running every single windows update, the disk space used is huge. This is mainly due to all the hotfix / updates and their rollback data, etc.

I agree that in a production environment I want the ability to rollback any hotfixes that I may add in case something breaks that was not thought of. However, for a fresh installation of windows on a new box I'd rather it was just a clean installation with all the latest updates.

Is there a way of installing all the service packs and updates and then cleaning up the machine afterwards to it uses less disk space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to your windows directory, you will see a lot of $ntuninstallKB$ directories. For example - c:\windows\$NtUninstallKB961371$\

In addition to individual KB updates above, service packs are located in the $hf_mig$ directory.... Take a look for other dollar directories as well as these are usually always updates.

Personally, I wouldn't remove them - however, having said that, I have never rolled back a update so maybe I should remove mine! :S